# Calculating binary of array using array.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

I have tried to calculate binary of a number provided in an array using naive for-loop method.
Than I find a solution which works but I am not able to understand how it is working.
I need help to understand this.

```js
const binaryArrayToNumber = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((a,b)=>(a<<1|b),0);
};
    

console.log(binaryArrayToNumber([1,1,1,1]))
```

Comment: WHat part of it don't you understand? Do you understand how the binary operators `<<` and `|` work?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explaining your code:

The `<<` [**left logical shift**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Logical_shift)) shifts the number to the left. If the number `n` is `00010110` then:

1. `n << 1` will be `00101100`.
2. `n << 2` will be `01011000`.
3. etc

The operator `|` ([**betwise or**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)) performs an iclusive logical OR on the bits at the same positions. If the numbers `n` and `m` were, respectively `00110100` and `10010101` then:

```
n     = 00110100
m     = 10010101
----------------
n | m = 10110101
```

following these rules: `0 | 0 = 0`, `0 | 1 = 1`, `1 | 0 = 1` and `1 | 1 = 1`.

---

Now for the [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) part: `reduce` loop through an array, passing an accumulator (initially set by the user, the last parameter) and the current item of the array to a callback (the function passed as the first parameter) and set the value of the accumulator to the returned value of that callback.

So for each item in the array we shifts the accumulator to the left to make a place for the new bit and then add the bit to that place using the betwise or. Here is an example with explanation:

```
var arr = [1, 0, 1];
```

1. `reduce` will start with an accumulator equal to 0 (`...,0);` at end of `reduce` line) then pass it along with the current item (the first item) to the callback. The the callback will shift the accumulataror (`a`) to the left by 1:

First shift the accumulator:

```
a = 00000000;
a << 1 = 00000000;
```

And then return the betwise or result of the shifted `a` with the current item from the array `b`:

```
b = 00000001;
00000000 | b = 00000001;
```

Now the new accumulator is the result of the above code (`00000001`).

2. `reduce` then will pass the current accumulator along with the current item from the array (now the second one) to the callback again:

First:

```
a = 00000001;
a << 1 = 00000010;
```

and:

```
b = 00000000;
00000010 | b = 00000010;
```

3. reduce will do the same thing for the last item of the array:

First:

```
a = 00000010;
a << 1 = 00000100;
```

and:

```
b = 00000001;
00000100 | 00000001 = 00000101;
```

4. Since there is no more items in the array, `reduce` will return the accumulated value (the accumulator return by the last call to the callback **i.e** `a`) as the result.

---

If the syntax `return arr.reduce((a,b)=>(a<<1|b),0);` isn't clear for you, it's because you're not familliar with [**Arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The exact line could be written using regular functions like this:

```
return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { // a the accumulator, b the curent item from the array
    return (a << 1) | b; // return something to store as the new accumulator
}, 0; // 0 is the initial value of the accumulator
```

### Another way to do it:

without using any binary operation nor `reduce`:

```js
var arr = [1, 0, 1, 1];
var number = parseInt(arr.join(''), 2);

console.log(number);
```

`arr.join('')` will return a string (a concatenation of all the items in the array `"1011"`). Then `parseInt` will parse that string as being a binary number.

Comment: Thanks !! Great Explanation. But as the output is the decimal number. So, just want to confirm, will the reduce function uses parseInt('000001001', 2) to convert it in decimal  number before returning.

Comment: @aayush No not at all. The binary operations (like shifts and betwise or) work on the numbers them selves. `var a = 2; a = a << 1;` `a` is a number without using `parseInt`. Because `parseInt` work only on strings. That gave me the inspiration for the second approach (see **Another way to do it** in my answer). All I was doing is explaining your provided code. Note that the second way is much better!!

Comment: Thanks !! @ibrahim That what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function works as an accumulator. The (a,b) pair is actually (total, currentValue). For instance, if you want to calculate sum of 1, 2 and 3, you can use the following code for that:

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(
   function(total, currentNumber){ return total + currentNumber; }
, 0);
```

For each iteration, a value of the *total* variable is increased for *currentNumber* and after all elements of the array were iterated, the *total* is being assigned to the *sum* variable.

The second parameter of the anonymous function (in this case 0) is the initial value of the sum (before iterating the array elements).

So, the code above is same as this code:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <=3; i++)
{
   sum = sum + i;
}
```